# What exactly is the "schwa" sound?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, stress-reduction

What exactly is the "schwa" sound? As a non-native speaker, I hear this sound as not being a pure and clean sound. I mean I know that every vowel sound may vary depending on whether the syllable is stressed, on the accent of the person that makes the sound, etc. But generally this sound is the same in the sense that it does not depend on the consonant sounds that come before or after, and might or might not be heard as being different by the non-native speaker ear.

The schwa sound is a very difficult one for me because I cannot find a pattern to follow. When I was learning the other vowel sounds I could analyze a long list of words being pronounced (by the same person of course) and then abstract the sound so I can produce it perfectly. But this does not work for the schwa sound. So for example I hear one sound in words like **a**-bout, b-**a**-loon, decim-**a**-l, and a different sound in words like s-**u**-ppose and impet-**u**-s, t-**o**-day or t-**o**-night. Also in words like Ros-**a**-'s and ros-**e**-s, the schwa sounds differently.

When it comes to words that have the schwa sound on vowels **e** an **i** like in the word insan-**i**-ty then the sound is almost the one for the **i** in t-**i**-p, but also in words like b-**e**-hind I hear some people say it with a schwa sound like in **a**-bout and some other people pronounce it like the **i** in p-**i**-t. So, I would really appreciate an explanation about how you perceive this sound and how you would explain it to someone who, like me, is not a native speaker.

Comment: My guess is that you haven't run across the site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) yet, or you would have asked this question there.

Comment: All (completely) unstressed vowels in English lose all character and become barely-heard schwas in the overall sentence.  It does not matter how they’re spelled or what they’re near.

Comment: @Daniela Diaz: You don't say what language(s) you speak, so we can't say whether there is a [ə] or a /ə/ in your language. If your language happens to be Spanish, then there is neither, and pronouncing it is certainly a problem in English.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sorry. Yes my language is Spanish.

Comment: @J.R. Your link takes me to this same place, but I googled English Language Learners in stack exchange and then I can see the site, thanks for that and sorry I will make my questions there next time.

Comment: @J.R. Whoa! See the Prof's answer -- that's for ELU, not ELL.

Comment: @tchrist JL says it's *shwa* not *schwa* -- see below.

Comment: +1 for the amount of background research effort by a non-native English speaker.

Comment: Teresa Pelka "Travelers in Grammar" Part One http://books.google.co.in/books?id=AHQiG26XdaoC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=%22shwa+or+schwa%22&source=bl&ots=URtNvYY0Io&sig=uZGKM39vYPwRr7IWKKHfAneiIVk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m1k0Ub-vFpHjrAeB0oGAAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22shwa%20or%20schwa%22&f=false

Comment: @DanielaDiaz: No need to say "sorry"; you should feel welcome to frequent both sites and ask questions at either place. This particular question could be asked to either audience, I think, although you may have gotten a more basic answer at ELL. Many non-native speakers are not yet aware of the other site, though, so we like to mention it when we can – not as a way of saying, "You're in the wrong place," but as a way of saying, "If you like this place, you might like that place, too."

Comment: If you look at [this webpage](http://aschmann.net/AmEng/#Vowels), you will find that some Americans have two weak vowels (ones that can occur in completely unstressed syllables), and some have as many five weak vowels (thus pronouncing *Erin* and *Aaron* or *roses* and *Rosa's* differently). The same kind of thing goes on in British dialects. Most of these are being called "schwa" by your teacher. Native English speakers generally don't pay much attention to the vowels in completely unstressed syllables, so you don't need to get these correct to be understood.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in the "roses"/"Rosa's" minimal pair, only the second syllable of "roses" is actually unstressed. In "Rosa's," the second syllable has *secondary stress*. Syllables with secondary stress aren't as emphasized as those with primary stress, but they do have vowels pronounced with their actual letter values instead of the shwa sound.

Answer (score 11):

First, it's "shwa". It's a Hebrew word, not a German one, so there's no reason for *SCH*.

Second, it's both a phone [ə] in IPA, **and** a phoneme /ə/ in English.
As a phone, it's got the sound of the final vowel in German *Danke*, of the first vowel in French *Le Mans*, or the first vowel in English *the man*. There is no shwa in Spanish or Italian.

Third, as a phoneme in English, /ə/ doesn't contrast with any other central vowel, so it has a lot of allophones: /ə/ [ɨ] [ə] [ʌ] (in increasing order of stress and decreasing order of speed), plus syllabic resonants [ṃ] [ṇ] [ḷ] [ṛ], before those consonants.

The best way I can suggest to practice the sound [ə] is to open your mouth to say an [e] (whatever that you think that is in your language), and then — while saying it, and without changing how your mouth or lips are positioned — move your tongue backwards toward the center of your mouth.

What you wind up saying is likely to be something close to a shwa.

Comment: Isn't there a better example than "the man"? The "e" could be pronounced "uh" or "ee".

Comment: I pronounce the *le* in *Le Mans* with the same vowel sound as the *oo* in *book.*  Whereas the last *e* in *Danke* is more like the *e* in *get*.  and The *e* in *the*, assuming it not pronounced *thee*, is more like the *u* in *uphill*??

Comment: @asmeurer: No, _the_ is pronounced "thuh" /ðə/ before consonants and "thee" /ði/ before vowels. /m/ is a consonant, so it's /ðə'mæn/.

Comment: I've never heard of that rule, and I'm pretty sure it's not universally used.  Usually pronunciation guides aim to be the same regardless of accent.

Comment: @asmeurer You’ve “never heard that rule”? Really? It’s the same one that’s operative in choosing *a* for “*a* banana” versus *an* for “*an* apple”. John is completely correct; this is ultra-basic English.  One says /ði/ apple but /ðə/  banana.

Comment: Several dictionaries I looked at give the spelling as *schwa* and the etymology as German. See [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=schwa&allowed_in_frame=0) for example: *1895, from German Schwa, ultimately from Hebrew shewa "a neutral vowel quality," literally "emptiness."*

Comment: That's over a hundred years old, and it's in archaic Yiddish spelling. We're talking about modern English here.

Comment: Well, John, I have to say that the Hebrew you cite is older than Yiddish. So where's your "modern" and where's your "English" now?

Comment: That's why the SCH. Yiddish used to transliterate Hebrew words like German, using SCH for **שׁ** [ʃ] (where modern Yiddish uses SH). The original was "shəva" or "shəwa" a "furtive" vowel (as they used to call it) that turned out to be variously pronounced, but mostly was a central or centralized or epenthetic vowel, pretty much like English /ə/.

Comment: @Robusto: Yeah, it is either an English or an international word, so either pick some form that reflects the origin of the English word (shəva/shəwa or schwa) or what I believe to be the international form (schwa). I don't see what modern Hebrew has to do with it...

Comment: Modern Yiddish transliteration. But never mind. Spelling is irrelevant for a word that 90% of English speakers never heard of.

Comment: @JohnLawler Excellent answer. Although I still can't produce the sound I'm working on it. Just a last thing. When you English speakers reduce your vowels to shwa sound, are you aware of it? I mean maybe you just think of the 'real' vowel that you would use when you say it with enfasis and then you unconsciously reduce it to this sound. For example, I don't know if this is possible but lest suppose you use the word 'typical' so you think of the sound 'i' as it really is and then withouth being aware of it, you reduce it to the shwa sound.

Comment: Then, that's the reason why I hear that the shwa sound in 'suppose'  seems to be an 'u', the shwa sound in the word 'about' sounds like an 'a' and the shwa sound in 'movement' sound like an 'e' but being a very short sound.

Comment: Most American English speakers don't know they're doing it. If you look in an American dictionary you'll see they don't use the IPA symbols; they use  weird local system invented 200 years ago by Daniel Webster, that uses jots and tittle, plus italics, to decorate the spelling letters. Nobody ever learns it, but it's ours, so American dictionaries continue to use it, like feet, inches, and stones.

Comment: @JohnLawler Not only do American dictionaries not use the schwa (sorry) from the IPA, IIRC, they used a symbol like a perpendicular sign ⟂ over a vowel whose sound degenerates into schwa. And when you think about it, not all schwas sound alike, at least, to me.

Comment: Yeah, it's hopeless. But American dictionary makers think Americans are too stupid to learn IPA. And I have to admit it seems they're correct.

Comment: The Hebrew spelling is not *shwa,* but שְׁוָא. When *schwa* was adapted into English, there was no official transliteration scheme for turning Hebrew into Roman letters. Consider Hannukah, Chanukah, Hannukkah,

Answer (score 5):

You have a good ear. In fact, for many speakers, the vowels in "Rosa's" and "roses" are not identical on average. It may be misleading to transcribe them with the same symbol "ə".

You might find the answer I wrote to another question relevant: [Exodus word pronounciation - Why it is different from spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362675/exodus-word-pronounciation-why-it-is-different-from-spelling/362679#362679) (based on "[The phonetics of schwa vowels](http://web.mit.edu/flemming/www/paper/schwaphonetics.pdf)" by Edward Flemming)

Basically, the realization of  what is called the "schwa" varies depending on its position and the surrounding sounds.

When schwa comes before a liquid or nasal such as /l/, /r/, /n/, /m/, the combination is commonly pronounced as a syllabic consonant. Syllabic /l̩/ would be possible (at least in some accents) in "b-a-lloon", and usual in "decim-a-l".

Word-final "schwa" tends to be pronounced with a low-ish vowel quality, phonetically something like [ɐ]. (It may be relevant that in this position it is almost always spelled with the letter "a", and it's basically in complementary distribution with the phoneme /ɑ(ː)/ which doesn't really occur in unstressed open syllables.) This sound may remain the same even when suffixes like "-s" or "-'s" are added, so many speakers use something like [ɐz] at the end of "commas" or "Rosa's". In non-rhotic British English, this is the same sound that occurs at the end of the word "lett-**er**".

In the middle of a word, schwa tends to be pronounced with a higher vowel quality, and it assimilates in frontness to nearby sounds. For some accents, it is actually usual practice to distinguish two different kinds of reduced vowels, normally transcribed /ɪ/ and /ə/; and it's /ɪ/ that occurs as the epenthetic vowel before the /z/ of inflectional endings, as in "roses" /roʊzɪz/. Even in accents where schwa is transcribed here, it will often be an /ɪ/-like schwa. Sometimes, to represent this or to represent the possibility of variation between ɪ/ and /ə/, the symbol /ɨ/ or /ᵻ/ is used for the vowel in words like "roses".

Adjacent labial consonants like /b/ and /m/ would tend to contribute to a "back-er" pronunciation of schwa (closer to /ʊ/ or /ʌ/), while adjacent coronal consonants such as /s/ and /t/ would tend to contribute to a fronter pronunciation of schwa (closer to /ɪ/) in s-**u**-ppose, impet-**u**-s, t-**o**-day or t-**o**-night.

Another relevant factor is voicing. Any vowel in English will be pronounced with shorter duration before a voiceless consonant; this includes schwa. When schwa is both preceded and followed by a voiceless consonant, as in "s**u**ppose", it may be [devoiced](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189568/77227).