# pronunciation of the 'ous' in dangerous

Tags: pronunciation, ipa

When I look up the word dangerous, the IPA spellings almost always show up as /ˈdānj(ə)rəs/

Maybe it's regional (Southern Ontario), but I don't encounter that pronunciation lot. And I probably use it myself less than 5% of the time.

I'd say, and maybe my IPA is off, 80% of the time I say /ˈdānj(ə)rɪs/. The 'ous' uses the ɪ sound, the same as in the word 'in'. And it's not subtle either. It's really really noticeable.

If I search 'dangerous definition' in Google, I get the above IPA, and a sound file. But the sound file pronounces the 'ous' *closer* to how I pronounce it, using ɪ as in 'in'.

In WordReference, it has the /ˈdānj(ə)rəs/ IPA spelling and a sound file that I think matches it. That sound file, of the word's US pronunciation, produces a pronunciation that is not one I hear often, as I said, maybe 5% of the time.

Both /ˈdānj(ə)rɪs/ and /ˈdānj(ə)rəs/ sound natural to me, but I only ever find the latter written, tho I mostly hear the former.

Also, I'm only focusing on the 'ous' part of the word, not the rest, because I there are several other pronunciations which of the first part of the word which sound natural to me also, so let us ignore them here.

Question :

Is it a sensible observation that the 'ous' in words like 'dangerous' are *commonly* pronounced as /ɪs/ and not /əs/ ? Or perhaps, the former is gaining favor ? I'm not sure if I can attach a sound file here, tho maybe I will upload my pronunciations to youtube, if there is no alternative.

EDIT:

I recorded myself saying it 3x with /əs/ and 3x with /ɪs/. I've never used soundcloud before and my file is 10 seconds long and if you don't use soundcloud **the default appears to be autoplay, which might be considerably louder than my file**, so listen closely, but not too closely.

https://soundcloud.com/dactyrafficle/dangerous?si=5623403900c9489789b1d4860060ebf6

Comment: [link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dangerous?q=dangerous)

Comment: Actually it's more likely a high central allophone [ɨ] of the central vowel phoneme schwa /ə/. Since there is only one central vowel phoneme in English (compared to 4 front and 4 back vowel phonemes), there is a lot of room for variations, and they get rounded, nasalized, and moved up, down, right, and left -- but they're still /ə/. That's the point of phonemes; we don't have to notice the individual differences as long as we recognize the phoneme.

Comment: I am working on a sound file. It's so hard to pick out by ear but I'm trying to say the 2 side-by-side and pull apart the sounds. The 2 pronunciations in the link provided by @BillJ sound a bit different to each other, but not as different as the first audio (the deeper voice) when compared to mine.

Comment: I think different people pronounce it differently.  I have heard the rhyme with the vowel in “in” but also in “us” and in “push” and probably in “ess”

Comment: It's dangerish to contradict the (purported) pronunciations of the IPAd guys.

Comment: Your ISS and USS are quite close to my ear. I have heard the ISS before, and if you hear it around you, than that is what you hear. You must also hear OTE & ABOTE, and ARONED in Ontario, the most distinctive difference that Americans hear in Canadians.

Comment: @YosefBaskin if I lived on Mars in the 1950s possibly, I might hear those. The 2 versions are fairly distinct : in the first I nearly sprain my tongue, and the second my tongue just hovers about.

Comment: Some previous questions that I think are relevant: [Why is the pronunciation of "Exodus" different from the spelling?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362675/why-is-the-pronunciation-of-exodus-different-from-the-spelling), [What exactly is the "schwa" sound?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105977/what-exactly-is-the-schwa-sound?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As John Lawler commented:

> Actually it's more likely a high central allophone [ɨ] of the central vowel phoneme schwa /ə/. Since there is only one central vowel phoneme in English (compared to 4 front and 4 back vowel phonemes), there is a lot of room for variations, and they get rounded, nasalized, and moved up, down, right, and left -- but they're still /ə/. That's the point of phonemes; we don't have to notice the individual differences as long as we recognize the phoneme.